# grails webflow requested resource not available

Tags: grails, spring-webflow

I'm using grails 2.4.2 and the webflow-plugin :webflow:2.1.0-SNAPSHOT (the stable one 2.0.8.1 throws compile errors on 2.4).
The applicatin start without errors, so I hope everything is fine...

And now I'm trying to define a webflow...

In my controller I have the following code:

```
def newPartnerFlow() {
    createPartner {
        on("addAdresse").to("finish")
        on("cancel").to("finish")
        on("save").to("finish")
    }

    finish {
        redirect controller: "stGsPartner", action: "index"
    }
}
```

and to start the flow from the PartnerIndex-view, I have the following code:

```
<g:link class="btn btn-default" action="newPartner">Create WEB-Flow</g:link>
```

if I click now on the button in the index-page, I get the following error from tomcat:

```
message /MyApp/stGsPartner/newPartner

description The requested resource is not available.
```

Do I miss something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in older versions of webflow that I have used, the flow definitions had to be defined as closure variables rather than methods.

```
def newPartnerFlow = {
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! My mistake was, that I thought the closure definitions in older versions of grails were changed to methods, the same would be for the flows. Tried the flow with a closure and it works!